# Importing Go source and coverage into SonarQube

Tags: go, sonarqube, cobertura, sonar-runner

I have a Go project that I would like to import into SonarQube 5.1, using SonarRunner.

I know it's not one of SonarQube's supported languages so I have set the property

```
sonar.import_unknown_files=true
```

to accomplish some basic level of import - and it does the job. The project also has code coverage in Cobertura format, generated using https://github.com/axw/gocov/ and https://github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml.

I have not been successful in getting this XML to import with settings:

```
sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=coverage.xml
```

Hence the project appears as a gray box on the Sonar dashboard. Has anyone done something similar and got it working? Is it because Go is an unsupported language?

Many thanks!

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Since [SonarQube 7.9](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-9-lts/) (July 2019), the go language is officially supported.
That includes [code coverage for Go](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/).
And it is supported in the [community edition](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/overview/)!

[40 rules for Go were present since SonarQube 6.7](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/analysis/languages/go/)  .

But the legacy [`SonarSource/sonar-go`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-go), the  Go Analyzer for SonarQube, is now SonarQube LTS) par of [**`SonarSource/slang`**](https://github.com/SonarSource/slang) (SonarSource Language), which is a framework to quickly develop code analyzers for SonarQube.
See [MMF-1670](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1670) (Migrate Go to SLANG)

> SonarGo is relying on the UAST technology developed early in the ideation phase of an unified language to write language parsers, which later led to the creation of SLANG.
>
> In order to unify the technologies we use, reduce the maintain cost, and benefit from more features, **we need to migrate the current SonarGO implementation to a GO plugin relying solely on the SLANG framework**.

See [its Go code coverage SLang issues](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARSLANG-399?jql=text%20%7E%20%22coverage%20go%22), in particular: [`SONARSLANG-399`](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARSLANG-399)

```
sonarqube {
  properties {
    property 'sonar.sources', '.'
    property 'sonar.exclusions', '**/*_test.go,**/generate_source.go,**/*_generated.go,**/build/**,**/.gogradle/**'
    property 'sonar.tests', '.'
    property 'sonar.test.inclusions', '**/*_test.go'
    property 'sonar.test.exclusions', '**/build/**,**/.gogradle/**'
    property 'sonar.go.tests.reportPaths', "${project.projectDir}/.gogradle/reports/test-report.out"
    property 'sonar.go.coverage.reportPaths', "${project.projectDir}/.gogradle/reports/coverage/profiles/github.com%2FSonarSource%2Fsonar-go%2Fuast-generator-go.out"
  }
}
```

[SONARSLANG-408](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARSLANG-408) ("[Go] Import Go Cover report") is still in progress though.
(But is only 4 hours old, at the time of writing)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to my knowledge the [SonarQube Cobertura](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Cobertura+Plugin) plugin only allows to import coverage reports for Java (and maybe supported JVM based languages).

However, if you are willing to do some transformation on your coverage result file, the [Generic Test Coverage](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage) plugin might suit your needs.

Comment: The generic coverage plugin is deleted, to bad

Comment: for more on generic test coverage:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Generic+Test+Coverage